# Split testing layouts for Djang-CMS

Tags: django, django-cms, ab-testing

I know there are things like django-experiments which do split testing at the python level. What I need is a tool to have multiple published versions of a single page in django-cms and a way to toggle between them. Basically we want to split test layouts of a page more than actual functionality to see what has the best user retention. I haven't found any good examples of how to implement anything similar to this with django-cms.

I don't need to have any form of analytics tracking or anything included in the tools. I honestly don't even care if it's an existing tool or just some ideas on where to start looking to make my own updates. I've been attempting to reverse engineer their code to see if there are ways I can update their editor to handle this myself as I've not found any existing tools to handle this.

Comment: Such functionality doesn't exist in CMS. The closest you could get at an application level is to have multiple pages where the differences you want to implement are served using different templates.

Comment: That is what I figured. I'm currently attempting to create my own system but because it's probably going to involve more than just a simple plugin and I can't devote a ton of time to it, it will probably be a bit before I have anything. I'll post an answer of my own when/if I figure something out.

Comment: There is the django-cms segmentation plugin. It has been left untouched for years but I think I was able to test it with minimal updates for Django-Cms 3.6 or 3.7. Since then there was new forks made. It's not a/b testing but it may be a part of a solution.